# Visual Studio 2019 : cycle trough nested files

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I would like to develop or use an existing extension that allows to cycle between files that are nested together in my solution.  By default, VS2019 cycles between an .cshtml and a .cshtml.cs with the F7 key (view.viewcode).  We've just added another nested file under the cshtml (a .ts), and it would be really usefull to switch from one to another by a key press.

Any ideas how to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension to group files with the same name and quickly switch between them. To switch from one to another by a key press, assign a shortcut to the **TabsStudio.OpenCorrespondingFile** command.

Comment: thats cool but it is a commercial product, I am looking for free solution

Answer (score 0):

Finaly did my own VSIX extension.
You can download it here : 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CarlVerret.CycleThroughFiles-001